# Searching a number different from others in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

I'm searching for a method in Java to find a number in an array, which is different from the others. This number also have to be the sum of others numbers.

I tried the method binarySearch to find if the number is already existing for each, but it works only if the unique number is the first element of the array.

Thanks for help !

```
public static boolean assert0() {
    int uniqueNumber = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
        int numberSearched = Arrays.binarySearch(number, number[i]);
        if (numberSearched < 0) {
            uniqueNumber = number[i];
            System.out.println("Nombre unique :" + uniqueNumber);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate and please explain your problem

Comment: Give an example of input and output to make the question clearer.

Comment: With the code I wrote up there, I try to find a number in an array which is existing only one time. So I try with binarySearch, but the unique number is only found when it's the first number in the array.

Comment: To find a single unique number in an array you use `xor`.  This is completely different than finding a number which is different than others, or which is the sum of other numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To find a unique value you could sort the array. Then all equal values are grouped together. Traversing the array can give you a unique value if there is.

Now the hardest part is the sum. What you want is equivalent to [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete. Everyone who finds an efficient solution to this problem, is going to win the Turing award. What you can do naively is to generate all subsets and check if their sum is equal to the unique value you found.

But If you mean the unique number must be the sum of **all** other numbers then it's easy. You traverse the whole array and sum the rest of the numbers. Then you check if this sum is equal to the unique element.

Comment: Ah okay thanks, I tried before to sort the array but I was wrong, I didn't understood how to do it. For the sum I think that I can additionnate each value in a for loop and when 'i' is equal to the index of the unique number, I continue the loop.

Comment: Maybe OP meant the selected number has to be sum of **all** other numbers. In that case, just compute sum of the numbers and divide it by two.